# Meaning of conditional statements in if[] then statement in makefile

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements

What is the meaning of following conditional statements used inside "if":

```
@if [ ! -d "${OPENSSL_SOURCE_PATH}" ]; then \
fi

if [ -e "${OPENSSL_TAR_PATH}/${OPENSSL_TAR_FILENAME}" ]; then \
fi
```

Where can I find information about all such conditions like -d, -e, -f etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man test`

(And your question is about shell, not make).